# Sum of the series of real numbers.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to find the sum of the series $$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4.2!}+\frac{1}{5.3!}\cdot\cdot\cdot$$ The given series is equal to $$\frac{2}{3!}+\frac{3}{4!}+\frac{4}{5!}\cdot\cdot\cdot$$ now i am stuck. How to proceed further? Please help.

Comment: By $4.2!$ do you mean $4$ multiplied with $2!$?

Comment: What does 4.2! mean?  Usually, factorials are only defined for non-negative integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac{n}{(n+1)!} = \frac{(n+1) - 1}{(n+1)!} = \frac{1}{n!} - \frac{1}{(n+1)!}$$

Comment: yes thank you...

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{n}{(n+1)!} &=& \sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{n+1}{(n+1)!}-\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\\&=&\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{n!}-\sum_{n\geq 3}\frac{1}{n!}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}.\end{eqnarray*}$$